# I can't get my CSS block to position correctly

Tags: html, css

I have created this CS block, its a bit messy.

```css
div.OSDCScreen .block_center {
  align-content: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-image: url('../Images/OSDCBack.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 595px;
  height: 836px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

but the part I'm struggling with is. I want to dictate the `width` and the `height` of the block and have it sit centrally on the page.

```css
align-content: center;
```

works and so does

```css
width: 595px;
height: 836px;
```

But when I use the together `align content` stops working and the block sites on the left of the screen like there is no position set.

Any tips of a someone new to this lark?

Comment: I think you need to use `display:flex` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp

Comment: *centrally on the page*  you expect vertical or horizontal center ? or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your margin to auto that should center it.

```css
div.OSDCScreen .block_center {
  align-content: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-image: url('../Images/OSDCBack.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 595px;
  height: 836px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin 10px auto;
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

the `align-content: center` can only be used in `flexbox` layout check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/align-content), all you need is `margin:auto`

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-image: url('//dummyimage.com/595x836');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 595px;
  height: 836px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

if you want to use  `flexbox`, you set `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to the parent

```css
section {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex
}
div {
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-image: url('//dummyimage.com/595x836');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 595px;
  height: 836px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```